# Не могу сохранить данные модели Yii

Tags: yii, activerecord

Есть моделька `CActiveRecord Img`, в ней есть свойство `images`. Когда приходит массив с данными то я в методе `afterSave` пытаюсь сохранить картинки в связанную табличку

моделька

```
class MainTsee extends CActiveRecord {

public $images = array();

 public function tableName()
{
    return '{{main_tsee}}';
}

public function rules()
{ //some right validate... }

  protected function afterSave() {
       if( parent::afterSave()) { 
        if(!empty($this->images)) {
            //save images
            foreach($this->images as $img) { 
               $img = new ImgSee;
               $img->slug = $img;
               $img->id_see = $this->id;
               $img->save(false);
            }
        }
        return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Вот код контроллера который принимает данные с массива POST

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['MainTsee']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['MainTsee'];
        if($model->validate()) {
                        $model->save(false);
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                    }
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Проблема в том что в массив `images` не передаются данные при операции присвоении атрибутов - `$model->attributes=$_POST['MainTsee']` и получаю пустой массив

Comment: а там точно $model->save(false);

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась изменением метода afterSave в модельке

```
 protected function afterSave() {

        if(!empty($this->images)) {
            //ImgSee::model()->insert();
            foreach($this->images as $img2) { 
               $img = new ImgSee;
               $img->slug = $img2;
               $img->id_see = $this->id;
               $img->save(false);
            }
            return parent::afterSave();
        }
    }
```